# PHP and "turning on" mysqli

Tags: php, macos, mysqli

I'm having trouble finding documentation about how exactly to go about "turning on" mysqli.  I'm running OS X SL and, as I understand it, since php5 is installed, the mysqli extension should already be there as well.

Is this as simple as adding a LoadModule line to php.ini?  If I need to re-compile php, does anyone know of a good link where I could follow along to do that (so I don't goof anything up)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save yourself the headache and install the [entropy PHP package](http://www.entropy.ch/software/macosx/php/) or [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/). Getting all the commonly needed PHP modules working on OSX is non-trivial. Most people I know go with either one of those packages.

### Update:

A lot has changed since I originally posted this answer. These days, the most straight forward thing to do on OSX is to use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh).

Comment: I've heard of MAMP before and thought about using it...  If i install it, though, am I then going to have duplicate apache/php/mysql installations on my machine?  Is that going to mess with what's already there?

Comment: I looked in to MAMP a bit and I think I'll be installing it and getting rid of this problem altogether.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: if you're serious about developing is  really bad idea, even getting the latest version of PHP is not easy

Answer (score 4):

[PHP.net said](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php):

> As of PHP 5.0, MySQL support is no longer enabled by default with the
>   standard PHP distributions.

You will need to configure PHP with MySQLi-support. Why don't take the safe (and probably best), object oriented, road and go with the [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo) classes?

Comment: +1 Also for the suggestion of PDO.  I'll be putting PDO to use as I develop in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to install the MediaWiki on Snow Leopard with MySQL 5.1.41, which needed this as well. After plenty of stumbling around, the solution was extremely simple...

In /etc/php.ini, change the following lines from:

pdo_mysql.default_socket = /var/mysql/mysql.sock
mysql.default_socket = /var/mysql/mysql.sock
mysqli.default_socket = /var/mysql/mysql.sock

to:
pdo_mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
mysqli.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock

While I had linked /tmp/mysql.sock to /var/mysql, this didn't kick in until I actually edited the file.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this same issue.

You need to make sure phpMyAdmin configuration file config.inc.php has the extension pointing to mysqli not mysql which is the default.

Answer (score 0):

If php5 was compiled with mysqli support already, then all you should need to do is point to that library in php.ini

```
extension=mysqli.so
```

After adding that you will probably need to restart apache.

**Note:** The filename for the mysqli library might differ on some platforms.