# Question about phpMyAdmin config.inc.php file

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I've never used PHP or MySQL before, so this is all new to me. I'm trying to set up EasyAPNS so that I can send push notifications to iOS devices, and in order for this to work, I need MySQLi to be enabled. Well, I can't seem to figure out how to do that exactly... However, in phpMyAdmin's config.inc.php file I did notice this line:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
```

If I change mysql to mysqli will MySQLi be enabled then? See the link below, this is why I think it should work. Thanks for your help!

http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/mysqli

This is in php.ini. Is it commented out right now? What's the deal? Once it is uncommented, then changing the config.inc.php file should put it in full effect, right?

[image]

Comment: Try it and have a feedback. Which language did you use before PHP ?

Comment: I'm all Objective-c, and about a day of C and C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If im not mistaken mysqli should be enabled in the php.ini file. PHPMYADMIN is just an interface where you can adminster your DB. It has nothing to do with the application that you create. To actually turn on mysqli open your php.ini file then locate a line called

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

and uncomment it. But for this to work your php must be compiled with it. To make sure of that restart your apache server and run

```
phpinfo();
```

Comment: I'm using a Mac Server, so I don't think it would be DLL, do you know what the extension would be?

Comment: Got it!! Please see the picture in my edit above. Is it enabled right now?

Comment: From ur pic its commented out. Remove the Semicolon and then restart your server. It should come into effect.

Comment: If I uncomment both the MySQL and mysqli DLLs, will those conflict with each other? I'm curious about that...

Comment: I am not sure why you would wanna do that. Mysqli is an extension of mysql and all that you do in mysql can be done in mysqli hence there is no reason for you to have them both

Answer (score 1):

If your PHP installation has the mysqli extension installed and enabled, this should work. Enabling it depends on what OS you're using to host it all. Generally, it will be either compiled in or loaded as an extension in php.ini so check your documentation on how to do this.

To check for mysqli, perform `php -i` from a command prompt and look through the output. It will tell you everything that your PHP installation can do.

Comment: It does say MysqlI Support => enabled, so if I enable it in the config.inc.php file, is there any messing around I have to do in the php.ini file?

Comment: Is there any way of telling if it is ON or OFF using php -i? Not whether it is actually there, but whether it's working?

Comment: If it says that it is enabled then you should be good to go. I believe that if php -i shows something as enabled then it is available for use. In the past if I've installed PHP from an RPM on linux, php -i shows how it was compiled in the first section but if an entension is not loaded then it doesn't display information regarding that extension later on (so it could show that it was compiled with `--with-mysqli` but, without the extension being installed, no information regarding mysqli is shown later on)

Comment: Ok, so it SHOULD be working now? As I said, nothing to do in the php.ini file? The config.inc.php file changed to MySQLi should be enough? I'm sorry, I'm about to pull my hair out over this problem.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it should be OK to change the config.inc.php file. You won't need to reload your webserver for the change to take place so it'll be quick to change it back again if it doesn't work. The best thing to do is to open the config.inc.php file in an editor, change the setting, save the file but **don't** close it, check phpMyAdmin works and, if not, change the file back again and re-save it. If you do need to enable the extension, check this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460167/php-and-turning-on-mysqli]. Sorry I can't be of more help - I use Linux for PHP